# Online record system

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Good day all!

This is a novice question and any help I can get will be GREATLY appreciated! I want to make the system as described below, but have NO idea where to start!

At the core of my project I want to design a website that fulfills these criteria:

1. People navigate to it on their web browsers
2. They will log in with an account/password
3. They will enter data into a text field
4. Their input should be parsed before submission
5. They hit 'submit' and that data gets pushed into a database of their information
6. They can download all their information as a text file by clicking 'download archive'

The things that I expect to be an issue of which I haven't a clue how to tackle are:

1. How to manage an authentication username/password system
2. Save user information to a database and have that database queued for user data by the webpage
3. How to submit data from a webpage and have it stored on a remote server
4. How to set each of these servers up and what platforms (SQL for database, ASP .NET for site, ruby on rails for data processing, etc...) I should use

THANKS! Any constructive input is appreciated

Comment: All of those outlined in your questions falls into what could be found on Google. 1-3 hours of research/downloading/configuring/uploading/testing should get you up and running.

Comment: I'm sure, but if there are any best practices or tutorials anyone recommends that would help me out tremendously

Comment: Way too broad a subject. We'll be commenting till the cows come home.

Comment: OK... here are a few pointers. Don't store passwords in plain text nor MD5. Use `crypt()` or PHP (5.5)'s `password_hash()` function. Use `mysqli_*` functions with prepared statements or PDO. *Plus*, remember to **never trust user input**. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails itself will take care of your criteria 1 to 5. However, you need to spend a few more effort to export data from database and save it as a text file. You may also use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) as a better solution for authentication (criteria 2) and Simple Form (just google simple form rails. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links) to handle forms more easily (criteria 3).

If you are new to rails, I recommend you to read the first few chapters of Agile Web Development with Rails or [this online tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#book_menu).
These will also cover your issues 1 to 3. For issue 4 you could use whatever (mysql, postgresql, sqlserver, etc.) you like as the database, you can choose rails build-in web server (webkit) or thin as a server for development; for production app, you may use a combination of apache/nginx and passenger. These are just a few suggestions. Of course there are more options out there. Choose what fits you best :)

Since your question is too broad, I can only post some resources to help you start. Check out the tutorials first until you get the hang of rails. Then check out other gems which could save you tons of time and could also help you build a more robust system.